# Eclipse PDE: xml text editor

Tags: xml, eclipse, editor, pde

I have a plugin that add to Eclipse an editor based on `MultiPageEditorPart`. One page shows the raw data using a `TextEditor`. Cause raw data is an XML file, I would switch to a more suitable editor.

Does exists an extension of `TextEditor` for XML, ready-to-use, shipped with Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Web Tools component includes a XML editor. Use `Help > Install New Software`, choose your main Eclipse repository and look in the `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development` section. Depending on which Eclipse download you used you may already have this. Source code for this is available in the `http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/kepler/` repository.

Alternatively one of the Examples in the Eclipse `New > Project > Plug-in Project` wizard is a basic XML editor.

There are other Eclipse projects (such as [Eclipse EMF](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html)) which are designed to help produce multi-page editors like this.